# React Navigation Stack Navigator Back Button Styling for Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have implemented a Stack Navigator as follows:

```
const MainNav = StackNavigator({
    notes: { screen: NotesScreen },
    addNote: { screen: AddNoteScreen }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'notes'
});
```

Now when I go from my `NotesScreen` to my `AddNoteScreen` I get the back arrow as expected. However, I've styled my header for `AddNoteScreen` using the following `navigationOptions`:

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'Add a note',
    headerStyle: {
        height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 54 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 54,
        backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 0,
        color: 'white'
    }
})
```

Now the `headerTitleStyle` doesn't affect the back arrow on Android. How can I make the back arrow on android adopt the same styles as the `headerTitleStyle`?

This is an image of the current problem:

[image: Demo of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property **headerTintColor** in navigationOptions which can be used to change the back button icon color. Except that there is no other option right now in **react-navigation v1.0.0-beta.11** to customise back button.

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'Add a note',
    headerStyle: {
        height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 54 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 54,
        backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 0,
        color: 'white'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white'
})
```

BTW instead of handling Status bar height in header styles, just render StatusBar component of react-native inside your root component like

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

class AppWithStatusBar extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        <MainNav />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Then render this 'AppWithStatusBar' component

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('your_app', () => AppWithStatusBar);
```

Comment: Right, found out that my project version doesn't support that yet. I solved the issue with using a view and the status bar height. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Why not hidding a status bar in Android ? :

```
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (

     <View style={{flex : 1}}>
       <StatusBar hidden = {true}/>
       <Search/>
     </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I made this post that functionality didn't exist.

Comment: But yeah thanks for the answer, I'm sure it'll help others in the future. It's just not relevant to the question.